# Can't get Odata service configured correctly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I can't seem to get my Controller and Mappings configured correctly.  I am able to connect just fine if I revert to a standard ApiController and default mapping, but can't connect using the EntityController type and OData mapping.  I get a 406 error back, from the server when trying to reference localhost:port/odata/persons My code...

(PS - All of my references and bindings seem to be configured correctly...no errors of any sort.)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //Create Entity Data Model
        ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Person>("Persons");

        //Configure Endpoint
        Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
    }
}


 public class PersonsController : EntitySetController<Person, int>
{
    static IList<Person> _peeps = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() {ID = 1, FirstName = "Ringo", LastName = "Starr", BirthDate = new DateTime(1940, 7, 7)},
        new Person() {ID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Lennon", BirthDate = new DateTime(1940, 10, 9)},
        new Person() {ID = 3, FirstName = "Paul", LastName = "McCartney", BirthDate = new DateTime(1942, 6, 18)},
        new Person() {ID = 4, FirstName = "George", LastName = "Harrison", BirthDate = new DateTime(1943, 2, 25)},
    };

    // GET api/person
    [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return _peeps.AsQueryable();
    }

    // GET api/person/5
    protected override Person GetEntityByKey(int id)
    {
        return _peeps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple scenario that should have worked.

Also you would need to use `localhost:port/odata/Persons` (Persons instead of persons). OData Uris are case sensitive.

Comment: The casing was the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll give you double points if you can tell me why, for the love of all that is holy, the routes are case sensitive.

Comment: The OData specification requires entity set names to be case-sensitive. It's unfortunate. I think there's a work item for enabling case-insensitive OData routing for a future version of Web API.

Comment: Shocking they missed that...

Anyways...here's a workaround. Though obviously putting in every permutation would be incredibly annoying.  I'm sure there's a better way by overriding some class but this is quick and dirty for now...

    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Person>("Persons");
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Person>("persons");